# How are standard function arguments evaluated into AssignmentExpression in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript

I am digging up through ECMAScript specification in attempt to find out how a function call must be carried out.

Before calling a function it is prescribed (inside an [`EvaluateCall`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-evaluatecall) routine (step 3)) to apply `ArgumentListEvaluation` steps with function arguments. To fulfill it a parser must tinker around with a heart of `Arguments`, `ArgumentList`. This list productions are [as follows](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ArgumentList):

```
ArgumentList [Yield, Await]:
  AssignmentExpression [+In, ?Yield, ?Await]
  ...AssignmentExpression [+In, ?Yield, ?Await]
  ArgumentList [?Yield, ?Await], AssignmentExpression [+In, ?Yield, ?Await]
  ArgumentList [?Yield, ?Await], ...AssignmentExpression [+In, ?Yield, ?Await]
```

In other words, `ArgumentList` is defined through `AssignmentExpression`. I can't get the idea how  a parsing of `foo(a)` can results in `a` to be an `AssignmentExpression`. In fact, [`AssigmentExpression` productions](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-AssignmentExpression) by no means helps me with it:

```
AssignmentExpression [In, Yield, Await]:
  ConditionalExpression [?In, ?Yield, ?Await]
  [+Yield] YieldExpression[?In, ?Await]
  ArrowFunction [?In, ?Yield, ?Await]
  AsyncArrowFunction [?In, ?Yield, ?Await]
  LeftHandSideExpression [?Yield, ?Await] = AssignmentExpression [?In, ?Yield, ?Await]
  LeftHandSideExpression [?Yield, ?Await] AssignmentOperatorAssignmentExpression [?In, ?Yield, ?Await]
  AssignmentOperator: one of *=/=%=+=-=<<=>>=>>>=&=^=|=**=
```

How can a variable, such as `a`, be accommodated here?

Comment: I would keep your question limited to the "how" question you have at the end of your question body, and away from the "why" question you have in the title. The title is likely to run afoul of opinion-based closure due to its need for speculation, since most people were not around when the spec was being written.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey agree, fixed

Comment: assignment expression is just any expression, except expressions that have a comma operator, as a comma will be interpreted as an argument separator. This just means that if you want to pass a comma-operator-expression as argument to a function, you must enclose it in parentheses. As `a` is an expression, it is allowed. But also `a+1`, `a || b && c` or `a = f(a) ** 2` are allowed expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ECMAScript 2020 standard, this is the chain of composition that shows how a token like `a` can be an `AssignmentExpression` production.

[AssignmentExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-AssignmentExpression) : [ConditionalExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ConditionalExpression) : [ShortCircuitExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ShortCircuitExpression) : [LogicalORExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-LogicalORExpression) : [LogicalANDExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-LogicalANDExpression) : [BitwiseORExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-BitwiseORExpression) : [BitwiseXORExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-BitwiseXORExpression) : [BitwiseANDExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-BitwiseANDExpression) : [EqualityExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-EqualityExpression) : [RelationalExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-RelationalExpression) : [ShiftExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ShiftExpression) : [AdditiveExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-AdditiveExpression) : [MultiplicativeExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-MultiplicativeExpression) : [ExponentiationExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ExponentiationExpression) : [UnaryExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-UnaryExpression) : [UpdateExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-UpdateExpression) : [LeftHandSideExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-LeftHandSideExpression) : [NewExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-NewExpression) : [MemberExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-MemberExpression) : [PrimaryExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-PrimaryExpression) : [IdentifierReference](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-IdentifierReference) : [Identifier](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-Identifier). Past that you get into the lexical grammar of the language.

That's how `a` can be an `AssignmentExpression`.

Comment: Would've been nice if you could have taken out the important parts and quoted it and then use the link as reference. Now, if the links were to break the answer would be rendered useless.

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder no it wouldn't. This describes the chain of composition unambiguously. Doesn't matter if the links work, they're just there if people want to prove that it's true, not necessarily to support the content of the answer.

Comment: Oh, as it turned out, it is a long way. I didn't condiser to walk further than `ShortCircuitExpression`

Comment: @Mergasov I just went down this chain myself; at first, I was confused as well, and didn't follow the links too far, but then I remembered that in JavaScript pretty much everything implicitly converts to bool, so in some abstract sense, it's a "conditional expression". And out of the options given, there was nothing else in the production that made sense - so down the rabbit hole I went...

Comment: @FilipMilovanović the language grammar has absolutely nothing to do with implicit conversions. The order of composition determines the relative precedence of the production parsed. Notice how part of the chain here follows the [operator precedence table here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) from 6 upwards.

Comment: @Filip Milovanović probably it would be great the spec'd supply some visual shortcut of production chains

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sure, but what I meant was, the fact that identifiers can be truthy/falsy is semantically related to the fact that they fall under (or can be reached via) the abstract names "conditional expression"/"short-circuit expression"/"logical expression" (i.e., that they chose to give these particular names to these nonterminals). In some other language, when reading, I'd proceed on the assumption that I don't necessarily need to look under "conditional expression", and it wouldn't be a bad guess.